# How to get public transport stops for the whole country in OSM (using overpass)?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to get data from OSM about public transport stops (including bus stops) using OverPass. It works nicely on city level, however when I attempted to acquire data for the country level I realized that some stops are missing. I checked manually that "Królewska" stop appears in "Warszawa" 5 times, but for the country "Poland" (in which "Warszawa" resides) it only appears once as a stop.

Here are my queries:

This one is working as expected:

```
[out:json];
area[name="Warszawa"];
(node["public_transport"="stop_position"](area);
<;
);
out center;
```

But this lacks some stops:

```
[out:json];
area["ISO3166-1"="PL"][admin_level=2];
(node["public_transport"="stop_position"](area);
<;
);
out center;
```

I tried a few different things (changing area, admin level, setting up a rigid bounding box) but none of them helped.

I'd be grateful for any ideas.

**EDIT:**

As always solution was simple and subtle - second script downloaded all stops but when I peeked at it in Jupyter Notebook it didn't show the whole response (but still displayed output was huge), ending it with "..." at the bottom. After manually searching for "Królewska" stops in the data I found that nothing is missing.

Comment: Add your solution as the answer to the question so it will help others in similar situation.

Comment: As described in the added "EDIT" I simply didn't see "..." at the end of the displayed output which meant that it wasn't the full output. When I manually checked the file, there weren't any missing stops. So basically the error occurred because I didn't carefully looked at the output.

Comment: Please don't add "solved" or similar phrases to your question when you've solved the problem. If someone gave you an answer, [accept it](/help/someone-answers). If you found a solution on your own, [post an answer](/help/self-answer) (you can also accept your own answer after two days). Accepting answers is also the way to show a question has been solved - editing "solved" into the question is not.

Answer (score 0):

Copied this solution from the OP

> As always solution was simple and subtle - second script downloaded
> all stops but when I peeked at it in Jupyter Notebook it didn't show
> the whole response (but still displayed output was huge), ending it
> with "..." at the bottom. After manually searching for "Królewska"
> stops in the data I found that nothing is missing.